# AnzographDB Documentation update needed

Tags: documentation, anzograph

Is there an error in the example given for inference of friends on the following docs page?

https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/v2.2/userdoc/inferences.htm?Highlight=inference#inference-example

I had to place an @ before the prefix in order to get the example working.

EDIT::

So a good look at the TURTLE w3.org page states both PREFIX and @prefix are fine.
But with PREFIX it appears there should not be a '.' at the end of the PREFIX line, so removing that works fine to load the ttl file as both a graph and an EXTERNAL source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. The update will be made.